# Is there a single word for people/ consultants who partner with our health?

Tags: idioms, british-english

We made a card for hospitals which introduces the doctors to its patients.

We named the card *Meet Your Healers*, but we need a new word to replace *Healers* now.

Comment: You made a what for hospitals? Some sort of publicity material? Educational material? Please supply more context. Also why is the word "healer" or "doctor" not appropriate?

Comment: It seems you [accidentally the whole thing](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally).

Comment: @oerkelens is that safe?

Answer (score 2):

Well, *healer* does have that meaning, but alas it is more often use of non-medical approaches.

"Health care professionals" and "health care practitioners" are both commonly used expressions, with the former in particular often used in such contexts.